# Fixing comxaudio decode timeout

Tags: raspbian, omxplayer, memory-split

On omxplayer, if I play a file, it often works the first time, then if I press `q` and play it again, I get

```
COMXAudio::Decode timeout
```

This apparently has to do with insufficient memory being allocated to my raspi (specifically raspi2), see [here](http://stupidstuffihadtofix.blogspot.ca/2014/05/raspberry-pi-256mb-openelec-4-xbmc-13.html).

I tried changing the memory split to be 128 and 128 through `raspi-config`, then restarting, but when I run the below command, I get different memory splits.

```
$ vcgencmd get_mem arm
arm=944M
$ vcgencmd get_mem gpu
gpu=64M
```

What is the correct way to solve this permanently on the raspi2?